React Native animation duration
Im trying to make an animation of progress bar of timer.
Im animating the Path
const AnimatedPath = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Path);
const pathLength = 224.5;
         <AnimatedPath
          d="M 260 151 A 109 110 0 0 1 100 245"
          fill="none"
          stroke="#048eff"
          strokeWidth="4"
          strokeDasharray={pathLength}
          strokeDashoffset={strokeDashoffsetOptimalInterval}
          strokeLinecap={'round'}
        />

Im setting interval on another screen and redux already have interval in milliseconds.
The interval should be not less than 1 hour. But when i start the animation i got an error -
First error - RangeError: Property storage exceeds 196607 properties
Second - * ERROR  Error: Exception in HostFunction: Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different.[[13,13,13,13,13,13],[4,4,2,3,18,20],[[28,{"offset":0,"value":224.5,"type":"value"}],[27,{"props":{"strokeDashoffset":28},"type":"props"}],[27,989],[28,27],[]],1102]*
const interval = useAppSelector(state => state.user.interval);
useEffect(() => {
    if (partTime.firstPartTime) {
      Animated.sequence([
        Animated.timing(strokeDashoffsetOptimalInterval, {
          toValue: 0,
          duration: interval * 1000,
          useNativeDriver: true, 
        }),
        Animated.timing(strokeDashoffsetNormalInterval, {
          toValue: 0,
          duration: normalInterval * 1000,
          useNativeDriver: true,
        }),
      ]).start();
    }
  }, [start, partTime, interval]);

I tryed to figure out what the problem is. Can anyone tell me is there a limitation of durarion React Native animation?
